# Setting Up Microsoft Exchange so that you may choose which account to send from

Tags: exchange

I have Microsoft Exchange Server 2003 set up which receives emails from a couple of domains.

However how do I set it up so you can choose which domain to send it from? Emails only send from the main Exchange Server domain. Isnt it possible to have a drop down just like Outlook if you have multiple accounts to choose what address the email is sent from?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Making a From box available is standard in Outlook I believe.  For example, in Outlook 2007 just select the option on the Options ribbon.

[image]

There are restrictions as to what you can put in there based on your Exchange configuration, which is something I can't help you with.